# Inserting only unique ID in form value in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I am new to React, there are two input fields in the application, one is for ID and another for Name, There are two components I've used, in the parent component I've maintained all the state and form in separate another component. My aim is to check the id which is a input from the user, id should be unique every time, if it's same, an alert should popup and the focus turns to ID input field, and it should do the same until the ID is different from all the objects(state object)

My app.js file is,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    names: [
      /*
        {id: 1,name: "Aashiq"}
        */
    ],
  };

  renderTable() {
    return this.state.names.map((eachName) => {
      const { id, name } = eachName;
      return (
        <tr key={id}>
          <td>{id}</td>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>
            <input
              type="button"
              value="Delete"
              onClick={() => this.deleteName(eachName.id)}
            />
          </td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  deleteName = (id) => {
    console.log("ID object", id);

    this.state.names &&
      this.setState({
        names: this.state.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id),
      });
  };

  addName = (newName) => {
    this.setState({
      names: [newName, ...this.state.names],
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Form onSubmit={this.addName} names={this.state.names} />

        {/* Table */}
        <br />
        <table id="details">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Names</th>
              <th>Operation</th>
            </tr>

            {/* Render dynamic rows
             */}
            {this.renderTable()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see I try to render the data as table and we can delete the row data also

The form.js file is,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import { uniqueId } from "lodash";

export default function Form(props) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [id, setId] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleChangeandValidate();
  };

  const handleChangeandValidate = () => {
    const { onSubmit, names } = props;
    console.log("Object keys length", Object.keys(names).length);
    if (Object.keys(names).length !== 0) {
      names.map((name) => {
        if (name.id === id) {
          alert("Enter unique id");
          setId("");
          document.getElementById("ID").focus();
        } else {
          //if different id
          onSubmit({ id: id, name: name });

          setName("");
          setId("");
        }
        return null;
      });
    } else {
      onSubmit({ id: id, name: name }); // first time
      setName("");
      setId("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} id="myform">
      <label style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        Name: {""}
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
      </label>{" "}
      <label style={{ fontSize: "20px", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
        ID: {""}
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={(e) => setId(e.target.value)}
          required
          value={id}
          id="ID"
        />
      </label>
      {""}
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: The browser output]

You can see I've tried to get the state and onSubmit function from the parent component(app.js) and done some logic like comparing all the ID's, but this logic throws some error, please somebody come up with a good solution.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code a bit and here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inserting-only-uniqe-id-uqizv?file=/src/App.js).

Here is what I did:

- I used [`createRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) to create two references that refer to each input field named `nameInputRef` and `idInputRef`.
- I added `ref={nameInputRef}` and `ref={idInputRef}` so that we can get their values on submit.
- On submit, I get the values of the name + id using their refs.
- to search for whether the ID exists or not, I used [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) which would return `undefined` if the same id doesn't exist in the list of names coming from the props.
- in `addName()`, I used `setState()` but in the param I used a function to make sure I get the latest list of names as updating the state is [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).  Inside I also used [ES6's destructuring feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to make a copy of the current list, push the new name to it and then update the state with the new list of names.

Comment: Man ,this looks legit , thanks for saving my day, indeed I too thought of using useRef(), and I learnt a impo lesson today,still want to know the async part in setState,can you refer me some good tutorials,it will be better in visual format.

Comment: Thanks, man! Glad it helped! :) So the idea is that React updates the `props` and the `state` asynchronously. This means that if you are going to depend on the value of the old state to set the value of the new state like in our case the list of names, we need to make sure we are accessing the latest value of the state at the time we are trying to update the state. This is done by passing a function to `setState()` instead of an object. You can check out the official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: cool man,btw can you please add a edit button  on the row fields and update the state changes synchronously in the same sandbox code above,this is haunting from my manager :(